# Оператор побитового сдвига uint = uint << uint;

Tags: c#, .net, битовые-операции

Не понимаю, почему второй операнд, должен иметь тип `int`, или оба `int`, если мне необходимо получить `uint`?

```
private const uint ScRedShift = 16U;
private const uint ScGreenShift = 8U;
private const uint ScBlueShift = 0U;

private const uint RedMask = 0xffu << ScRedShift;
private const uint GreenMask = 0xffu << ScGreenShift;
private const uint BlueMask = 0xffu << ScBlueShift;
```

Где можно прочитать про то как работает оператор побитового сдвига в `c#`?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#left-shift-operator-

Comment: Какая разница, какого типа второй операнд?

Comment: Ну например что бы не было отрицательного числа для сдвига влево/вправо? :)

Comment: тогда он должен быть byte или ещё меньше, никто ж не сдвигает на 255 позиций, и слева не должно быть чисел со знаком, а то `-4 >> 2` добивает единицами, а `4 >> 2` - нулями.